# How can I loop through functions using a list of variables

Tags: r, loops

I have a code where I create factors and then want to summarise, have a proportional table and unlikeability calculation:

```
myvars <- names(Diab[c(17:33)])

Diab[myvars] <- lapply(Diab[myvars], ordered, levels = c("No","Down","Steady","Up"),                   labels = c("No","Down","Steady","Up"))

summary(Diab$metformin)

round(prop.table(summary(Diab$metformin)),3)

unalike(Diab$metformin)

summary(Diab$repaglinide)

round(prop.table(summary(Diab$repaglinide)),3)

unalike(Diab$repaglinide)
```

.....

where

> myvars
>    [1] "metformin"                "repaglinide"              "nateglinide"
>    [4] "chlorpropamide"           "glimepiride"              "glipizide"
>    [7] "glyburide"                "tolbutamide"              "pioglitazone"
>   [10] "rosiglitazone"            "acarbose"                 "miglitol"
>   [13] "tolazamide"               "glyburide_metformin"      "glipizide_metformin"
>   [16] "glimepiride_pioglitazone" "insulin"

Instead of coding `summary()`, `round(prop.table())` and `unalike()` for each of myvars, how can I do this in a loop?
I know I can `summary(Diab[myvars])`, put the output is in columns and I want to retain the output in rows as follows:

```
summary(Diab$metformin)
    No   Down Steady     Up 
 22057    162   5310    275 
round(prop.table(summary(Diab$metformin)),3)
    No   Down Steady     Up 
 0.793  0.006  0.191  0.010 
unalike(Diab$metformin)
0.3340651
```

Thank you in advance for your solutions.

Comment: Per `r` tag (hover to see): Please provide minimal and reproducible example(s) along with the desired output. Use `dput()` for data and specify all non-base packages with `library()` calls.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consider reshaping your wide data to long format and then run `table` (equivalent to [`summary.factor`](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/rockchalk/versions/1.8.144/topics/summary.factor)) and `prop.table`. Doing so, you avoid any need for looping. Unfamiliar of definition of `unalike`, possibly from [ragree package](https://rdrr.io/github/raredd/ragree/man/unalike.html), it appears you can pass a data frame with named arguments.

```
Diab_long <- reshape(Diab[c(17:33)], varying = names(Diab), times = names(Diab),
                     v.names = "value", timevar = "metric", ids = NULL,
                     new.row.names = 1:1E4, direction = "long")

tbl <- table(Diab_long)

prop.table(tbl, margin = 1)

ragree::unalike(Diab_long, ...)
```

To demonstrate with seeded, random data:

**Data**

```
set.seed(22620)

lvls <- c("No","Down","Steady","Up")

# DATA FRAME OF ALL FACTORS
Diab <- setNames(data.frame(replicate(17, factor(sample(lvls, 10, replace=TRUE), 
                                                 levels = c("No","Down","Steady","Up")))),
                c("metformin", "repaglinide", "nateglinide", 
                  "chlorpropamide", "glimepiride", "glipizide",
                  "glyburide", "tolbutamide", "pioglitazone", 
                  "rosiglitazone", "acarbose", "miglitol", 
                  "tolazamide", "glyburide_metformin", 
                  "glipizide_metformin", 
                  "glimepiride_pioglitazone", "insulin"))


# RESHAPE TO LONG
Diab_long <- reshape(Diab, varying = names(Diab), times = names(Diab),
                     v.names = "value", timevar = "metric", ids = NULL,
                     new.row.names = 1:1E4, direction = "long")
```

**Output** *(does not include `unalike`)*

```
tbl <- table(Diab_long)
tbl    
#                           value
# metric                     Down No Steady Up
#   acarbose                    1  2      2  5
#   chlorpropamide              4  4      1  1
#   glimepiride                 6  3      0  1
#   glimepiride_pioglitazone    4  0      2  4
#   glipizide                   4  4      2  0
#   glipizide_metformin         2  3      3  2
#   glyburide                   3  2      3  2
#   glyburide_metformin         1  3      6  0
#   insulin                     1  1      5  3
#   metformin                   2  2      4  2
#   miglitol                    1  3      5  1
#   nateglinide                 6  3      1  0
#   pioglitazone                1  4      3  2
#   repaglinide                 1  4      2  3
#   rosiglitazone               1  7      1  1
#   tolazamide                  2  4      1  3
#   tolbutamide                 3  3      2  2

ptbl <- prop.table(tbl, margin = 1)
ptbl    
#                           value
# metric                     Down  No Steady  Up
#   acarbose                  0.1 0.2    0.2 0.5
#   chlorpropamide            0.4 0.4    0.1 0.1
#   glimepiride               0.6 0.3    0.0 0.1
#   glimepiride_pioglitazone  0.4 0.0    0.2 0.4
#   glipizide                 0.4 0.4    0.2 0.0
#   glipizide_metformin       0.2 0.3    0.3 0.2
#   glyburide                 0.3 0.2    0.3 0.2
#   glyburide_metformin       0.1 0.3    0.6 0.0
#   insulin                   0.1 0.1    0.5 0.3
#   metformin                 0.2 0.2    0.4 0.2
#   miglitol                  0.1 0.3    0.5 0.1
#   nateglinide               0.6 0.3    0.1 0.0
#   pioglitazone              0.1 0.4    0.3 0.2
#   repaglinide               0.1 0.4    0.2 0.3
#   rosiglitazone             0.1 0.7    0.1 0.1
#   tolazamide                0.2 0.4    0.1 0.3
#   tolbutamide               0.3 0.3    0.2 0.2
```

<kbd>[Online Demo](https://rextester.com/XNUER26563)</kbd>

Comment: Thank you Parfait. I struggled a bit and then realised that what I hadn't said is that my data contains 27,804 obs. and thus reshape() would result in 472,688 obs. So I changed new.row.names = 1:1E4 to new.row.names = 1:1E6 and it works perfectly. Thank you very much.

Comment: Yes indeed, change `new.row.names` to accommodate the data. Great to hear and glad to help!

Comment: Function unalike() compares vectors of factors for consistency, for a single vector of factors gives an equivalent of a coefficient of variation. So for the latter, need to be done one variable at a time. Any suggestions how to loop through the list of variables to form a table would useful. But thanks for your solution using reshape().

Comment: Per my comment at top. What `library` does that function derive? Please edit post accordingly. And check its docs to see if data frames/matrices can pass through.

Comment: 'unalike(x)' is in the 'ragree' package which is not in CRAN but from GitHub, where x is a vector of categorical data and can be a data frame.

Comment: Please see the docs page (as I linked in this solution) which suggest you can pass a data frame into the function. Give it a try on the long formatted data frame.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, but it results in an error: 
> unalike(Diab_long)
Error in unalike.data.frame(Diab_long) : 
  id, rater, score not found in data
If each variable is submitted one at a time, then the error doesn't occur 
> unalike(Diab$metformin)
[1] 0.3340651
To get the result I need, each variable needs to be submitted to unalike() one at a time.

Comment: Likely, if using a data frame you have to supply *id*, *rater*, and *score* args as mentioned in docs. However, to iterate across columns, keep your wide format and run for matrix: `unalike_matrix <- sapply(Diab[c(17:33)], unalike)` or for a list `unalike_list <- lapply(Diab[c(17:33)], unalike)`.

Comment: Perfect, @Parfait. Thank you very much.